# type inference when combining untyped and typed consts

Tags: go, types, constants

When declaring two const variables (one typed and one untyped), and printing out the type of the second one, like:

```
const x float32 = 10000
const y = 1e8 / x

fmt.Printf("the type of y: %T \n", y)
// or with reflect:
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(y))
```

it tells me, that `y` is of type `float32`.

Well this doesn't come as a surprise, since the the untyped const variable `y` is defined as dividing an untyped float constant by a typed float constant and therefore the type might be inferred.
According to "Go by Example" (https://gobyexample.com/constants), constants never have a type, unless explicitly provided. However, according to the official Go blog documentation, untyped constants **do** have hidden types that get inferred, but let the constant remain untyped until a type is needed.

I would have assumed, that `y` would still be an untyped float constant. However, when using it for assigning a new variable, Goland's inspector tells me, that the type can be omitted:

```
const z float32 = y 
//        ^^^ type can be ommitted
```

So finally, my question would be:
Is it impossible to declare an untyped constant out of typed constant expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the actual problem here is. The IDE suggestion seems to say that the type of `z` can be inferred from the type of `y`, so you can omit the explicit declaration. That seems correct.

The declaration of `y` is still untyped though, so what seems to be wrong? The inferred type of constants is affected from its constituents - they can't be ignored, otherwise you get a type mismatch. You may be interested to read [how type inference is typically implemented](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/type-inference/); this isn't necessarily the case for Go, but it should be a decent introduction in general to help you understand the underlying mechanism here.

---

Note that you could omit the type of `x` too, and the end result type would be `float64`, so all of it can be inferred without types.

Comment: Well yes, I do get, that all the types could be inferred, however, from reading the documentation of Go, I got the impression, that there's actually a difference between explicitly typed and untyped constants. Am I wrong there?

Comment: @PaezRice: yes there's a difference, as explained in https://blog.golang.org/constants

Comment: Okay, I guess my problem was the assumption, that my const would be typed, just because of the inspector's hint, that the type could be omitted when defining `z`. Thank you for clarifying, and providing this article about implementation of inference.